# Как избежать ошибки с циклическим импортом python

Tags: python

При запуске кода у меня происходит ошибка:

```
cannot import name 'connect' from partially initialized module 'sqliteconnector' (most likely due to a circular import) (d:\Telegram projects\1\sqliteconnector.py)
  File "D:\Telegram projects\1\logic.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sqliteconnector import connect
  File "D:\Telegram projects\1\sqliteconnector.py", line 6, in <module>
    import logic
  File "D:\Telegram projects\1\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sqliteconnector import db_creator as main_creator
```

Я понял, что ошибка связанная с циклическим импортом, но как его можно избежать? Кода довольно много так как пишу телеграм бота.

Comment: Чтоб можно было дать конкретную рекомендацию как разоврвать этот порочный круг импортов нужно чтоб вы показали схематически хотя бы структуру кода, т.е. что за компоненты зависят друг от друга (и значит импортируют друг друга). В частности, что такое logic и почему sqliteconnector  (вроде как независимый модуль, по идее) зависит от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто: не импортировать в файле А файл Б, а в файле Б файл А *(который будет опять импортировать файл Б, который будет опять импортировать файл А, который...)*

Comment: Могли бы добавить пример кода, в котором есть рекурсия и способ её решения, так как если я не буду импортировать с одного файла другое и наоборот, код попросту не запустится.

Comment: Не мог бы потому что так не делается, в чем вы уже смогли убедиться. Если у вас файлы "попросту не запустится", то нужно переделывать, чтобы запустилось. Честно говоря, не могу представить ситуации, где был бы необходим циклический импорт.

Comment: Можно ли тогда как-то иным образом получать с одного файла другое и наоборот?

Comment: Можно вынести все, что нужно получать, в третий файл.

Comment: Я начал выключать недавно написанный мною код ( закомментировав его ), после заметил, что `import logic` перестал отображаться, как активный где-либо в коде, я удалил импорт и всё нормально заработало, правда осталось подумать, как правильно перенести, то что мне нужно в другой файл :)